# Join 2 fetch responses into a single dataset

Tags: javascript

I'm using fetch to retrieve 2 datasets. Something like this:

```js
Promise.all([
  fetch(table1URL).then(response => response.json()),
  fetch(table2URL).then(response => response.json())
]).then(response => {
  let table1 = response[0];
  let table2 = response[1]
           
  let merged_data = .......         
})
```

I'm trying to create a new dataset called merged_data, which would be  data from both tables merged

The tables can be joined on the following fields via a left join;

- table1.name = table2.oldname

The resulting dataset would look something like this:

- column 1 = table1.name
- column 2 = table1.modifiedDateTime
- column 3 = table1.modifiedBy
- column 4 = table2.Modified
- column 5 = table2.oldname

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide some concrete examples of the two datasets and the result you want.

Comment: is the relationship one-to-one between both datasets? or can there be many rows in table2 for any given row in table1?

Comment: It's always one-to-one

Answer (score 2):

Index `table2` by the `oldname` property then map `table1` to the new format, pulling in matching `table2` entries when present.

```js
const table2Index = table2.reduce(
  (map, row) => map.set(row.oldname, row),
  new Map()
);

const result = table1.map(({ name, modifiedDateTime, modifiedBy }) => [
  name,
  modifiedDateTime,
  modifiedBy,
  table2Index.get(name)?.Modified,
  table2Index.get(name)?.oldname,
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. It basically turns table2 into an object where the keys are the oldname field of every row. Then using a map over table1 (left join) you create the new rows with each column set to the desired values from left_row and right_row.

```js
let table1 = [
  {name: 'a', modifiedDateTime: 'date', modifiedBy: 'user'},  
  {name: 'b', modifiedDateTime: 'date', modifiedBy: 'user'},
  {name: 'c', modifiedDateTime: 'date', modifiedBy: 'user'}
]

let table2 = [
  {oldname: 'a', Modified: 'dateFromTable2'},  
  {oldname: 'b', Modified: 'dateFromTable2'}
]

let right_table = new Map(table2.map(right_row => ([right_row.oldname, right_row])))

let merged_data = table1.map(left_row => ({
    column1:left_row.name,
    column2:left_row.modifiedDateTime,
    column3:left_row.modifiedBy,
    column4:right_table.get(left_row.name)?.Modified,
    column5:right_table.get(left_row.name)?.oldname
  })) 
console.log(merged_data)
```

Answer (score -1):

If both tables have lots of entries, I believe you should can make a map from table2 in which the keys are table2.oldname and values are the corresponding objects.

Thus you'd benefit from direct access to save cpu.

Then loop over table1 and access the mapped values directly.

Comment: 1. This is an answer, not a comment. 2. Nobody said it's stupid. 3. Please do not add meta-commentary into your post.